# Is there a "get:" attribute target?

Tags: c#, attributes

In Microsoft's docs I noticed [the following example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapdecoder.thumbnail?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Media_Imaging_BitmapDecoder_Thumbnail):

```
[get: System.Security.SecurityCritical]
public virtual System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource Thumbnail { get; }
```

Notice that the target "`get:`" is applied to the attribute.

However in their [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets) *there is no such target*. They list only:

`assembly, module, field, event, method, param, property, return, type`

I don't see anything version-specific on either of these pages.

---

Furthermore, the [C# language specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf) doesn't include `get:` either (page 395).

---

I tried using it anyway in a sample in VS 2015, and the IDE reported the error:

> 'get' is not a recognized attribute location. Valid attribute
>   locations for this declaration are 'property'. All attributes in this
>   block will be ignored.

**Is `get:` valid in some circumstances? Is it a mistake in their documentation?**

---

FYI it is very hard [if not impossible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267938/297415) to search for the string "get:" on SO. I expected to find an answer to this already but that made it pretty hard to do so.

Comment: It's not written like that in the [original code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Imaging/BitmapDecoder.cs,2b0303c942be10d5). I suppose this is a bug in the code that generates the documentation from the source code.

Comment: @NineBerry that seems pretty convincing, consider adding an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @nineberry, the example in the documentation shown in the question is not the same as the actual code of the .NET Framework. The question has:

```
[get: System.Security.SecurityCritical]
public virtual System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource Thumbnail { get; }
```

But [the actual code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Imaging/BitmapDecoder.cs,2b0303c942be10d5) is:

```
public virtual BitmapSource Thumbnail
        {
            [SecurityCritical ]
            get
            {
                ...
```

It was also suggested that this might have been a flaw in how the docs were auto-generated. I don't know how the docs are maintained but they have since been modified.

As of today [what the documentation shows is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapdecoder.thumbnail?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Media_Imaging_BitmapDecoder_Thumbnail):

```
public virtual System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource Thumbnail 
{ [System.Security.SecurityCritical] get; }
```

which is consistent with the code and does not use the ephemeral `get:` target.

This seems pretty convincing that there is no (and never has been) such a target.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything about `get:` target, but it is possible to apply atrribute only on `get` part of property or different attributes on `set` and `get`. Please see example below

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAttributeAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string name;

    public MyAttributeAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int Value
    {
        [MyAttribute("Get")]get;
        [MyAttribute("Set")]set;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Also `dotPeek` decompiler shows me `Thumbnail` property like

```
public virtual BitmapSource Thumbnail
{
  [SecurityCritical] get
  {
```

so it looks like that `get:` target does not exists